# Why is less inserting a space between class name and pseudo selector?

Tags: css, less

I trying to add a `:hover` pseudo selector using Less. But every time I try It adds a space between the class name and the pseudo selector.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this issue. Any help would be really appreciated!

Below is my code

**Less Code**

```
.well{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  :hover{
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

**Generated CSS code**

```
.well :hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&:hover`:

```
.well{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;

  &:hover{
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

> The `&` operator represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing selector
>
> *from http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature*

Comment: @MMarcinJuraszek  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Less adds a space because when you nest a selector under another, the nested selector is considered as a child or descendant (unless explicitly stated otherwise). In CSS, any selector of a descendant element is separated from the parent by a space and so the space is added.

The fix is to append the child to the parent selector `&`. This tells the Less compiler that the nested selector is actually not a child/descendant's selector but is actually an attachment to the parent.

```
.well{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  &:hover{
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for the explanation Harry

Comment: @json2021: Glad to know that you found it useful :)